# Are questions about adblocking on-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

Our help says that questions about "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" are off topic.  What about web browser add-ons, specifically configuring adblockers?

We've had [several](https://superuser.com/questions/1202926/using-ublock-origin-how-do-i-block-a-root-site-without-blocking-sub-pages) [great](https://superuser.com/questions/1157967/how-to-block-hot-network-questions-in-the-sidebar-of-stack-exchange-network) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/680824/adblock-plus-disabled-by-default-and-enable-per-site) on the site about adblockers, and have [a](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adblock) [few](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ublock) [tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ublock-origin) about them.  That said, [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122113/how-to-use-ublock-origin-to-block-hot-network-qutestions-without-blocking-all-th) was just [closed and migrated to WebApps SE](https://superuser.com/posts/1374334/revisions) for being off topic here.  So are questions about adblocking on-topic or off topic?

Comment: I would agree it shouldn't have been migrated, but only because, the question itself isn't clear.

Comment: I don't think this should have been migrated.  However, if your goal is just to block HNQ, that was asked and answered a couple of years ago.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1157967/how-to-block-hot-network-questions-in-the-sidebar-of-stack-exchange-network.

Comment: To this post, questions about software installed on your computer, including browsers and installed add-ons, are on topic.  Questions about web sites and web content generally aren't.  Neither are requests for recommendations for software or add-ons  So questions about blocking web content have to be carefully worded to clearly focus on using your installed software.

Comment: The migration has been rejected and your question reopened and closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @fixer1234 That question is about blocking the HNQ sidebar, whereas mine is about blocking the full-page HNQ list at stackexchange.com.  Similar motivation, but none of the answers to that question are applicable to mine.

Comment: @g.rocket, the full list is a dedicated web page.  Just don't go there.  Blocking a web site or suppressing the content of a web site is different from blocking ads.  It also isn't clear how landing on a blank page is acceptable, where landing on the same page with its content is a problem (when you can simply not go to the page).  Why go at all to a site you don't want to see?  Better explanation might help.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you sure you want to blank the whole page of SE homepage instead of only HNQ? Personally, SE homepage is my navigation page to All Sites & Filtered Questions, which is still useful. On the other hand, have you tried the "block element" when right-clicking the specific element you want to block?

Comment: @Andrew Any solution that blocks the HNQ list from that page is a good answer to me.

Comment: @Andrew I tried that a while ago; IIRC there's no clear selector to use to pick out the list (it's just an unlabled div or something).

Comment: It's `stackexchange.com###question-list` (not really selectable from the picker, but `stackexchange.com###main-area` is close enough, if only it also breaks the layout)

Comment: @Andrew would that also block the list of questions from tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Andrew if you post that as an answer on [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1374334/how-to-use-ublock-origin-to-block-just-the-page-stackexchange-com-without-blocki), then if it works and doesn't block other stuff I'll accept it.